# Did I calculate the probability of a hash being generated that isn't unique correctly?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

- There are `16` possible characters (hexidecimal).
- The length of each string is `40`.
- total number of possible combinations or unique strings:

  - $16^{40} = 1461501637330902918203684832716283019655932542976$

∴ the probability of generating a unique hash is $1/(16^{40})$ ?

### For a bit more context TL:DR:

The objective is to calculate how long it will take to (probably) generate two random strings that are the same.

- we can generate `266000` strings a second:

  - $60 \times 60 \times 24 = 86400$ seconds in a day
  - $266000 \times 86400 = 22982400000$ strings a day
- $1461501637330902918203684832716283019655932542976 \div 22982400000 = 63592211315219599267425718493990315182$

it would take `63592211315219599267425718493990315182` days to generate two equal strings, probably?

that's a long time, if i got it right, see any errors? :D

Answer (score 2):

No, that would be the expected time to generate a particular string.  The time to create any string twice is a generalization of the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).  In effect the number of possible collisions grows with the square of the number of strings generated so you need to use a factor times the square root of the number of strings.

Comment: thanks, i'll edit that. the birthday problem is exactly what i'm looking at, i'll get into it, thanks again